# Sensitivity Table for IRR Using Purchase Price & Total Synergies

Tags: spreadsheet

For my DCF I have a line for Synergies to be entered for each of four years

How can I create a sensitivity table in Excel for IRR taking into variations in purchase price (enterprise value) and total synergies over a four year period. Is this even possible?

I'm not sure how to account for synergies produce in year 1 vs year vs year 3... etc. b/c of discounting

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [Money.SE]!  Please define your terms and add more tags so people who find your question know whether they can answer it and so people who can answer your question have an easier time finding it.  What do `DCF` and `IRR` mean?  What does `synergy` mean?

Comment: @dg99 DCF Dicounted cash flow. IRR Internal rate of return.